# unbound method must be called with instance as first argument

Tags: python, instantiation

I am trying to build simple fraction calculator in python2.x

```
from fractions import Fraction
class Thefraction:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b =b
    def add(self):
        return a+b
    def subtract(self,a,b):
        return a-b
    def divide(self,a,b):
        return a/b
    def multiply(self,a,b):
        return a/b

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        a = Fraction(input('Please type first fraction '))
        b = Fraction(input('Please type second fraction '))
        choice = int(input('Please select one of these 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4. multiply '))
        if choice ==1:
            print(Thefraction.add(a,b))
        elif choice==2:
            print(Thefraction.subtract(a,b))
        elif choice==3:
            print(Thefraction.divide(a,b))
        elif choice==4:
            print(Thefraction.multiply(a,b))
    except ValueError:
        print('Value error!!!!!')
```

I am not sure that I made correct class that can be instantiated, however I used it like,`Thefraction.add` in side of `__name__=='__main__'`. Did I miss something?

Comment: Why are you using methods like that? Have you considered following a structured Python OOP tutorial?

Comment: You could use the `@staticmethod` decorator and put a and b in the params for add.

Comment: At the point you use `@staticmethod` decorators, you may as well drop the `__init__` method.  At the point you drop the `__init__` method you may as well make them functions instead of methods.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dont know that. Can you share that please?

Comment: Other than using decorator, did I miss something here? I didnt study decorator yet

Comment: @Jay Your problem is you're using a class for a situation where you shouldn't be using a class

Comment: He wasn't asking how to simplify or improve his code, only how to correctly instantiate a class.

Comment: @Keatinge really? I have answer code that the instructor didnt use class either. However, I wanted to make class and try to improve my skill...

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Right and Wrong. I want to improve my skill that if I miss something, I will know what I am wrong then can improve it

Comment: @Jay Exactly but you first need to learn how to properly use a Class and it's methods before learning when one is unnecessary.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I agree with that lol some reason I thought I could make it easily. Lol

Comment: You can, you were only missing a few steps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's meant to be done like this:

```
thefraction = Thefraction(a, b)
if choice == 1:
    print(thefraction.add())
```

Then in your class:

```
def add(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

and so on. Don't include `a` and `b` as parameters in the methods.

And yes, go through a tutorial on classes again. Thoroughly.

Comment: To the downvoter: it's clear that OP is a beginner who has just learnt about classes and is a little confused, and I am just trying to help. I do not believe I am encouraging laziness. I also know that this problem would be better solved with functions or static methods but that is not the point here: they are learning the basics of classes. And PLEASE explain your downvotes in future because I doubt they are as obviously justified as you think.

Comment: Thank you for your generosity, it was big motivation and encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't put `()` in front of your `theFraction` object. Even if you did, you will be faced by another calamity..You initialize your object with two variables (a,b) which means you will to call your object like

```
Thefraction(a,b).add(a,b)
```

I dont think you want this because **a** and  `b` are local variables in each methods.. which is kind of making variables that you do not need.
What I am assuming you would like to have is this.

```
  Thefraction(a,b).add()
```

here is the full code

```
from fractions import Fraction
class Thefraction:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b =b
    def add(self):
        return self.a+ self.b
    def subtract(self):
        return self.a-self.b
    def divide(self):
        return self.a/self.b
    def multiply(self):
        return self.a/self.b

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        a = Fraction(input('Please type first fraction '))
        b = Fraction(input('Please type second fraction '))
        choice = int(input('Please select one of these 1. add 2. subtract 3. divide 4. multiply '))
        if choice ==1:
            print(Thefraction(a,b).add())
        elif choice==2:
            print(Thefraction(a,b).subtract())
        elif choice==3:
            print(Thefraction(a,b).divide())
        elif choice==4:
            print(Thefraction(a,b).multiply())
    except ValueError:
        print('Value error!!!!!')
```

Comment: sheww..I haven't done so many edits in a long time since I have left SO..hee hee...

Comment: I think this is basically same as above one except @AlexHall instantiated, isn't it? Thank you for spending your time to help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it like you are using it, you should define your class methods as @classmethod and you do not need an init:

```
class TheFraction:
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, a, b):
        return a+b
```

This way of declaring methods indicate that they are not to be run in instances of the class but can be called like:

```
TheFraction.add(a, b)
```

Comment: OP is still confused about the basics of classes, this is only making it worse.

Comment: You are probably right, your answer is the correct way of doing it with an init. I was just providing an alternative and by the time I started my answer yours wasn't there ;)